# Trouble with React Native and Firebase RTDB

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using React Native (0.68) and Firebase RTDB (with the SDK, version 9), in Expo.

I have a screen that needs to pull a bunch of data from the RTDB and display it in a Flatlist.
(I initially did this without Flatlist, but initial rendering was a bit on the slow side.)

With Flatlist, initial rendering is super fast, huzzah!

However, I have an infinite loop re-render that I'm having trouble finding and fixing.  Here's my code for the screen, which exists within a stack navigator:

```
export function GroupingsScreen () {

... set up a whole bunch of useState, database references (incl groupsRef) etc ...

  onValue(groupsRef, (snapshot) => {
    console.log('groups onValue triggered')

    let data = snapshot.val();
    if (loaded == false)  {
      console.log('--start processing')
      setLoaded(true);
      let newObject = []

      for (let [thisgrouping, contents] of Object.entries(data)) {
        
        let onegroupingObject = { title: thisgrouping, data: [] }
        for (let [name, innerdata] of Object.entries(contents.ingredients)) {
          onegroupingObject.data.push({ name: name, sku: innerdata.sku, size: innerdata.size, 
            quantity: innerdata.quantity,
            parent: thisgrouping
           })
        }
        newObject.push(onegroupingObject)
      }
      console.log('--done processing')
      setGroupsArray(newObject) 
    

    }
    
  });

.... more stuff excerpted ....

return (
<View style={styles.tile}>
<SectionList 
  sections={groupsArray}
  getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
  renderItem={ oneRender }
  renderSectionHeader={oneSection}
  initialNumToRender={20}
  removeClippedSubviews={true}
/>
</View>
)};
```

I'm using loaded/setLoaded to reduce re-renders, but without that code, RN immediately dumps me out for excessive re-renders.  Even with it, I get lots of extra renders.

So...

1. Can someone point me at what's triggering the rerender?  The database is /not/ changing.
2. Is there a better way to get RTDB info into a Flatlist than the code I've written?
3. I have some code that actually does change the database.  That's triggering a full rerender of the whole Flatlist, which is visibly, painfully slow (probably because parts are actually rendering 10x instead of once).  Help?

For completeness, here's the OneItem code, so you can see just how complex my Flatlist items are:

````
const OneItem = (data) => {
  // console.log('got data',data)
  return (
  
  <View style={[styles.rowView, { backgroundColor: data.sku?'white': '#cccccc'}]} key={data.name}>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.nameView} onPress={() => {
    navigation.navigate('AddEditItemScreen', {purpose: 'Grouping', itemname: data.name, parent: data.parent, mode: 'fix'})
    }}>
  <View style={styles.nameView}>
    <Text style={styles.itemtext}>{data.name}</Text>
    {data.sku? null: <Text>"Tap to add SKU."</Text>}
    {data.size?<Text>{data.size} </Text>: <Text>no size</Text>}
    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>

  <View style={styles.buttonView}>

  <Button style={styles.smallButton}
          onPress={() => { changeQuant(data.quantity ? data.quantity - 1 : -1, data.parent + '/ingredients/' + data.name) }}
        >
          {data.quantity > 0 ? <Text style={[styles.buttonText, { fontSize: 20 }]}>-</Text>
        :<Image source={Images.trash} style={styles.trashButton} />}</Button>

    <Text style={styles.quantitytext}>{data.quantity}</Text>

    <Button style={styles.smallButton} 
      onPress={() => {
        changeQuant(data.quantity? data.quantity +1 : 1, data.parent+'/ingredients/'+data.name)}}>
        <Text style={[styles.buttonText, {fontSize: 20}]}>+</Text></Button>
  </View>
  </View>
  )

};```
````

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to stop the rerender (question #1).  So, within my Screen functional component, I needed to make another function, and attach the state hook and useEffect to that.  I'm not totally sure I understand why, but it gets rid of extra renders.  And it's enough to get #3 to tolerable, although perhaps not perfect.

Here's the new code:

```
export function GroupingsScreen () {
... lots of stuff omitted ...
    function JustTheList() {
      const [groupsArray, setGroupsArray] = useState([])

      useEffect(() => {
        const subscriber = onValue(groupsRef, (snapshot) => {
             console.log('groups onValue triggered')

            let data = snapshot.val();
              let newObject = []

              for (let [thisgrouping, contents] of Object.entries(data)) {              
                let onegroupingObject = { title: thisgrouping, data: [] }
                for (let [name, innerdata] of Object.entries(contents.ingredients)) {
                  onegroupingObject.data.push({ name: name, sku: innerdata.sku, size: innerdata.size, 
                    quantity: innerdata.quantity,
                    parent: thisgrouping
                  })
                }
                newObject.push(onegroupingObject)
              }
              setGroupsArray(newObject) 
 
          })
          return () => subscriber();
        }, [])

        return(
        <View style={styles.tile}>
          <SectionList 
            sections={groupsArray}
            getItemLayout={getItemLayout}
            renderItem={ oneRender }
            renderSectionHeader={oneSection}
            initialNumToRender={20}
            removeClippedSubviews={true}
          />
          </View>
          )

    }
```

And then what was my return within the main functional screen component became:

```
return (
  <JustTheList />
)
```

I'm still very interested in ideas for improving this code - am I missing a better way to work with RTDB and Flatlist?